# Connecting from local server to an online (Bluehost) MySQL database times out in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bluehost

I have a site on a Bluehost shared server with a MySQL database that I want to be able to connect to from my local Apache server. Here is the connection code I've used (I'm 90% sure all of the supplied information is correct).

```
$db = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db); // line 9.

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die ("MySQL connection error.");
}
```

What's interesting is that this code **does not** give a MySQL connection error. Rather, execution times out. If I change any of the connection variables it will give specific error information.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ...\connect.php on line 9
```

I also **do not** believe this is an error with server permissions. If I disallow my IP on Bluehost I get a different error message.

Comment: This certainly looks like an issue in their end. Contact them and they might be able to assist you.

Comment: To exclude problems with your local webserver settings etc., I'd try to connect with a different tool like MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Connected to Workbench with no problems with the same IP and port. I can access all the tables. Very curious that it's not working through PHP.

Comment: Other things you could try: Check firewall settings for PHP, double check and `echo` the connection parameters, set the port number explicitely.